# dereferencing array vs pointer

Tags: c++, c

I'm sure this has been asked before, but a cursory google and stack overflow search didn't turn up the answer.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char a[128][1024];
    strcpy(a[0], "hello");
    strcpy(a[1], "foo");
    strcpy(a[2], "bar");
    char **b = a;
    printf("%s\n", a[0]); //same as printf("%s\n", a)
    printf("%s\n", a[2]+1); //print from 2nd char of 3rd string
    printf("%s\n", b); //same as printf("%s\n", a), makes sense
    printf("%s\n", b[0]); //segfault???
}
```

First off, why is the last one a segfault? I'd expect same behavior as array `a`. How would I access the n-th string from b in a generalized way? What are the differences in treatment between a and b?

On a similar note, the way I understand it, `a[n]` is syntactic sugar for `*(a+n)`. Is this correct, both for pointers and for arrays? Yet it seems getting different behavior for `a` and `b`.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you've enabled all your warnings? And read all two million SO posts that tell you that an array is not the same as a pointer?

Comment: @KerrekSB Well clearly - that's what the code demonstrates. I just asked for an explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`char **b` says “At the place where `b` points, `b[0]`, there is a pointer to a char. And, if I use `b[1]`, `b[2]`,…, those are also pointers to char.”

In contrast `char a[128][1024]` says “`a` is 128 arrays of 1024 char.” When you do this, at the place where `a` is, there are no pointers. There are just char. In memory, it looks like 131,072 char in a row (128•1024 = 131,072).

When you assign `char **b = a`, assuming the compiler allows you to, you set `b` to be the address of `a`. When you use `b[0]`, there should be a pointer there. But there is not. There are just char there. When you pass `b[0]` to printf, the compiler goes to where `b` points, loads several bytes as if they were a pointer, and passes the resulting value to printf. Then printf crashes, because the bytes point to some bad location.

A proper definition of `b` would be `char (*b)[1024] = a;`.

Comment: Ah. That makes perfect sense. Thank you for the explanation. :)

Answer (score 0):

This

```
char **b = a;
```

is a type mismatch as `a` is `char[][]` which used without index is a `char *`.

You might like to switch an all compiler warning (on `gcc` this is doen via `-Wall`).

This line

```
printf("%s\n", b[0]);
```

dereferences a pointer to a pointer to character, that is an address value. Then it tries to print the address value value as a (0-terminated) string, what most likely is going to access random memory.